# No error message, redirect to DetailView using slug and get_absolut_url()

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I'm trying to link my **DetailView** to the listview and can't understand how to redirect my title blog to the **DetailView** template. This is my first project. I'm using slug and don't know if the problem is in here. There's no error message. Just don't work at all.

**models.py**

```py
class Story(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True, blank=True)
    report = models.TextField()
    pubdate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        'User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True
    )
    
    class Meta:
    
        ordering = ['-pubdate']
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('story-detail', kargs={'slug', self.slug})
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('allauthors/', views.AuthorsList.as_view(), name='all-authors'),
    path('allstories/', views.StoriesList.as_view(), name='all-stories'),
    path(
        'allstories/<slug:slug>/',
        views.StoriesDetail.as_view(),
        name='story-detail',
    ),
]
```

**views.py**

```py
class StoriesList(ListView):
    models = Story
    template_name = 'story_list.html'
    queryset = Story.objects.all()
    context_object_name = 'stories'
    
class StoriesDetail(DetailView):
    models = Story
    template_name = 'story_detail.html'
```

**story_list.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<ul>
{% for story in stories %}
    <li><a href="{{ title.get_absolute_url }}">{{ 
story.title }}</a> - {{ story.pubdate }} - <a 
href="{{ author.get_absolute_url }}">{{ 
story.author }}</a></li>
{% empty %}
    <li>Sorry, no story in this list.</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's due to a little typo in your `story_list.html` file. So instead of using this

```html
<a href="{{ title.get_absolute_url }}">
```

try this:

```html
<a href="{{ story.get_absolute_url }}">
```

This will work just fine. And also change this line

```html
<a href="{{ author.get_absolute_url }}">
```

to like this:

```html
<a href="{{ story.author.get_absolute_url }}">
```

But the above line only works if you extend your `User` model and define `get_absolute_url` method there.